# iptable Bad argument `ACCEPT'

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I am trygin the following..

```
#!/bin/bash

NOIPHOST=example.noip.me
LOGFILE=iptables_update.log

Current_IP=$(host $NOIPHOST | cut -f4 -d' ')

if [ $LOGFILE = "" ] ; then
  /sbin/iptables -I INPUT -m tcp -p tcp -s $Current_IP -j ACCEPT
  echo $Current_IP > $LOGFILE
else

  Last_IP=$(cat $LOGFILE)

  if [ "$Current_IP" = "$Last_IP" ] ; then
    echo IP address has not changed
  else
    /sbin/iptables -D INPUT -m tcp -p tcp -s $Last_IP -j ACCEPT
    /sbin/iptables -I INPUT -m tcp -p tcp -s $Current_IP -j ACCEPT
    iptables-persistent save
    echo $Current_IP > $LOGFILE
    echo iptables have been updated
  fi
fi
```

I am getting this error..

> Bad argument `ACCEPT' Try`iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more
>   information. iptables have been updated

I have also tried using these..

```
iptables -D INPUT -m tcp -p tcp -s $Last_IP -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -m tcp -p tcp -s $Current_IP -j ACCEPT
```

but still same error.

Anyway to fix this?

Comment: You might try running your script through http://shellcheck.net, but if the problem is with `iptables` (as seems likely), superuser.com is a better site for this question.

Comment: Thank you for the information it was usefull for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you don't have any newlines in your `$Last_IP` variable?
Can you try adding the following before your `iptables -D...` line?

```
Last_IP=$(echo $Last_IP|tr -d '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when `$Last_IP` or `$Current_IP` is empty.